# UWP: error while requesting start of a background task

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, background-task

I have an issue with my `UWP app` which has a background task started with an `ApplicationTrigger`.
 Sporadically, the `RequestAsync()` call on the `ApplicationTrigger` instance returns `ApplicationTriggerResult.UnknownError` result and background task is never run anymore. Restarting or rebooting the device is of no use. One has to re-install the application to fix the issue. Does any of you know what could be the reason to get an `UnknownError`? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Improved code markup

Answer (score -1):

A background task is triggered by a system or time event and can be constrained by one or more conditions. When a background task is triggered, its associated handler runs and performs the work of the background task. A background task can run even when the app that registered the background task is suspended.

You may refer to this Demo from Microsoft in Github:
[Background task sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTask)

```
foreach (var task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
        {
            if (task.Value.Name == BackgroundTaskSample.ApplicationTriggerTaskName)
            {
                AttachProgressAndCompletedHandlers(task.Value);
                BackgroundTaskSample.UpdateBackgroundTaskStatus(BackgroundTaskSample.ApplicationTriggerTaskName, true);
                break;
            }
        }

        trigger = new ApplicationTrigger();
```

Comment: This answer is an exact copy paste from the Github description. Please show some more effort in answering the question.

Comment: Update with Source Code

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @Cheah, but you don't answer to my question. My point is how to diagnose the problem when `ApplicationTrigger.RequestAsync()` returns `ApplicationTriggerResult.UnknownError`